# Can Sonar exclude files outside maven project? Also, can it exclude files other than Java?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a use-case where I have few image files (for my README page) outside of the maven project. I want Sonar analysis to skip performing analysis on that file. I tried keeping the file in the main project pom as below:

`<sonar.exclusions>**/*.png</sonar.exclusions>`

This still gives me the error:
`` [sonar4bitbucket] Failed to parse diff: string matching regex `\z' expected but `B' found ``

Any suggestions to skip `.png` images being allowed outside of maven project with Sonar analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure exclusions in the UI:

> At the global level, the navigation path is Administration > General
> Settings > Analysis Scope. At the project level, the navigation path
> is Project Settings > General Settings > Analysis Scope

*Source:* [Narrowing the focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/)

If you want to stay with maven properties, also make sure you do not override those in the build using `mvn … -Dsonar.exclusions=…`.

Also keep in mind that those property-basedd exclusions are not being stored in the Sonar DB. Therefore you might see an old coverage check jumping in which you might want to exclude as well:

```
<sonar.coverage.exclusions>
  **/*.gif,
  **/*.png
</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
```

Comment: I tried following the [source-Narrowing the focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) but since my files are outside the project, so passing the regex did not work for me. Also, changing the `sonar.sources` value will cause all the files in project to be considered but it will reduce the sonar coverage.

Comment: "but since my files are outside the project" – ah, good to know! I think it is correct that changing sonar.sources will change the coverage. Maybe you need to reorganize your project? Did you perhaps not use the maven standard directory layout?

Comment: Hey @Ben, my maven project is organized as per maven guidelines, though this file is doc file, which I have kept outside the source files. Btw got a work-around solution to push the binary files (images) directly to develop branch and bypass sonar check.